# Reporting returned international wire transfer

Tags: united-states, irs, international-transfer

I wired $40,000 to Portugal five months ago to purchase a property. The purchase failed and now $40,000 will be returned to my US account. Should this be reported to the irs?

Comment: so the actual effect is that you *didn't pay*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IRS requires that individuals and businesses file various 1099s for payments and transactions that occur during the course of business. A business must issue the most common form, 1099-MISC, for amounts paid in excess of $600 for services rendered.

In the case you mention, your transactions occur during the same year (and you would not have filed your taxes after the money was wired) so you simply record this in your accounting books. There is no form for reporting a returned wire or canceled payment. You will not claim the original $40,000 payment as an expense, either.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.

Comment: Please upvote and "mark as answer." This is how you signal to the community that it is a helpful response.